# Cannot iterate map through auto in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, maps, unordered-map, auto

I am trying to iterate this simple through auto feature but it is giving me tons of errors. I don't know what's wrong with this code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m = {
      {"apples", 5},
      {"bananas", 3},
      {"pears", 7},
  };
  for (auto& [fruit, count] : m) { //line 13
    std::cout << "I have " << count << " " << fruit << ".\n";
  }
}
```

> 13    [Error] expected unqualified-id before '[' token13
>
> 14    [Error] expected ';' before '[' token
>
> 13    [Error] 'fruit' was not declared in this scope
>
> 13    [Error] 'count' was not declared in this scope

And many more errors. I have read this example online and it is working fine there.

Comment: *Structured bindings* are a **C++17** feature, and therefore not available in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

[Structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) are a C++17 feature.

Iterating through the `std::unordered_map` in C++11 would look something like:

```cpp
for (auto const& p : m) {
    std::cout << "I have " << p.second << " " << p.first << ".\n";
}
```